# Similarity between bags of words

Tags: similarity, information-retrieval

I have three bags of words:

```
BoW1 = [word11, word12, word13]
BoW2 = [word21, word22, word23]
BoW3 = [word31, word32, word33]
```

BoW1 contains synonym words, BoW2 also contain synonym words. Both BoW1 and BoW are fixed. BoW3 contains words of a document, so it is multiset.

I want to search BoW3 to see if it contains any word of BoW1 and BoW2. Then, I would like to calculate the similarity between Bow1 + BoW2 and BoW3. So, together BoW1 and BoW2. I am **not** interested in calculating the similarity between BoW1 and BoW2,  in calculating I can assume that they are one. However, for my case, BoW1 contains significant words than BoW2.

What do you think is the best and accurate way to calculate such similarity. I though to use term frequency as in Information retrieval filed. However, I am not sure if repetition is important in my case.

Comment: The definition of "*similarity"" depends on your use case (which is why there are so many different similarity measures). Can you elaborate what the similarity between your sets is expected to express, i.e. can you  give a little more information about the search/retrieval scenario?

Comment: It is expected to express "relevance", I am using BoW1 and BoW2 because if I use one of them I expect to have many false positive result. Therefore, both bags together are expected to lessen false positive and thus return relevant documents. And as I stated in the question, BoW1 contains more important words than BoW2.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably wanting the cosine similarity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). Compute the dot product between each bag of words vector. If you're using Python, your code will look something like:

```
# Make sure each BoW is a map from word -> frequency
BoW1 = {word11: 1, word12: 5, word13: 3}
BoW2 = ...
BoW3 = ...

# Normalise the frequencies
BoW1_total = sum([freq for freq in BoW1.values()])
BoW1 = {word : freq / BoW1_total for word, freq in BoW1.items()}
BoW2_total = ...
...

# Compute the dot product
similarity = 0
for word in set(BoW1.keys()).intersection(BoW2.keys()):
    similarity += BoW1[word] * BoW2[word]
... # continue for each pair you want to work out the similarities
```

Of course, organise the code better than this ^ (write functions for all the things you need to do multiple times, etc) but this should give you the rough idea.